# How to install Windows 10 from Linux (Puppy) live CD

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, livecd, puppylinux

I have very old PC which has 4GB of RAM and can only install from CD (700MB) - no usb or DVD.

All I can do is load Linux Puppy http://puppylinux.com/index.html#download from Live CD and can see (mounted) my 500GB SSD where I need to install the system.

How can I do it? "add-apt-repository" seems to be not working in Puppy linux.

Thank you.

Comment: You can not install Windows 10 from within Linux. Only from an existing Windows installation or via bootable media (USB-Stick, DVD, ...).

Comment: Windows won't fit on a CD. It requires something closer to 6GB on a USB stick. If your machine is too old to boot from USB, it's almost certainly too old to run Win10. Specifics of the machine would help.

Comment: I have working internet can I download it somehow to the SSD disk as iso (If I manage to mount the NTFS drive as writable) or image and auto start during reboot from the disk somehow? There is a windows system already in that SSD disk but it does not boot even after fixmbr so reinstall may be needed...

Comment: I can also plug in USB but only in the Linux Live CD system not boot from it sadly so somehow prepare system from the SSD disk to boot

Comment: 'Preparing the SSD' won't help you to install Windows. You need the iso correctly written to a USB stick so it will boot & install from there. You cannot mount the iso on the fly to do this. Get a friend to make you the installer using Windows Media Creation Tool.